# Select query with no duplicate "First Letter" in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

How can I select data with no duplicate the "First Letter" value?
My table has a column named "title_raw" with data arrange follow "A, B, C, ..."
I want my data display something like this

```
Select (title_raw no duplicate first letter) from SONGS
```

Comment: Could you give a few more details about the tables involved, column types, etc.? What fields are you actually `select`ing?

Comment: can you give an example of some values from title_raw column. For example title_raw contains: 'aert', 'aaert', 'arr', 'tgd', 'uuu'; what do you want to have?

Comment: Ok, for example my data contains 'aert', 'aaert', 'arr', 'tgd', 'uuu'. I want to have 'a', 't', 'u',... not all the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT substr(title_raw, 1, 1) FROM SONGS
```

Comment: Thanks najmeddine! That's what I want!

Answer (score 1):

```
select substr(col, 0, 1) as Letter, count(primary_key) as Frequency
from table
group by Letter
```

Don't know if you can use column alias' in group by with SQLite. This will give you any first letters that are unique. Then use that as a subquery for:

```
select data
from table
where substr(data, 0, 1) IN (subquery)
```

That should work

Comment: What's "subquery" ? I don't understand?

Comment: I try your query but I don't know why It just work with number data?

Comment: First try running the first query, see if that works. You may need to change group by Letter to be group by substr(col, 0, 1)
Once that works replace subquery with the first query. It fetches all the first letters that are unique and then selects the rows starting with those letters.